# How can I add add vertical orientation to ItemsControl while also having the Scroll?

Tags: wpf-controls, material-design-in-xaml

I am creating a design that dynamically adds `materialdesign:Card` inside `ItemsControl`. My original design code is this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Something}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <materialDesign:Card>
                ....
            </materialDesign:Card>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

However, I didn't liked the output that looks like this:

```
 ----------------------------------------
| [ Card here ]                          |
| [ Card here ]                          |
| [ Card here ]                          |
 ----------------------------------------
```

I researched adding vertical orientation and saw previous SO topics that suggest to add something like this:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

Indeed, it somehow answered my concern:

```
 -------------------------------------------
| [ Card here ] [ Card here ] [ Card here ] |
| [ Card here ] [ Card here ] [ Card here ] |
 -------------------------------------------
```

**Problem** now is that there are still `Cards` not shown below so I needed a `ScrollBar` to go down further. Previous SO topics suggested to add `ScrollViewer`, so I did before my `ItemsControl`.

```
<ScrollViewer>
   <ItemsControl>
        ....
   </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

However, it leads back to the first result. Is there a way to achieve this? Perhaps a replacement for `WrapPanel` or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try wrapping your `ScrollViewer` with `DockPanel` like this:

```
<DockPanel MaxHeight="300">
   <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
      <ItemsControl>
         ...
      </ItemsControl>
   </ScrollViewer>
</DockPanel>
```

Notice that I added `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` property to your `ScrollViewer`, it is your choice if it would be `Vertical` or `Horizontal`.